# Cannot run PowerShell scripts in Azure Functions v2

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I'm trying to write a Function App using .NET Core in Azure Functions v2. When using the Microsoft.Powershell.SDK package from Nuget (required for .NET Core PowerShell runtime) I cannot get Visual Studio to copy the System.Management.Automation library to the bin with my Function App.

This results in the following error:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. TestPowershellInFunction: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=6.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load the specified file.
```

I've reproduced this in an existing Azure Function and a new Solution by simply creating a Timer function and adding the following snippet:

```
PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create();
IEnumerable<PSObject> result = shell.AddScript("Write-Output 'Hello, World!'").Invoke();

foreach(PSObject line in result)
{
    log.LogInformation(line.ToString());
}
```

This works on a new Console App with the PowerShell Nuget installed, but when added to the Function App I get the error. I do notice that System.Management.Automation doesn't get put in the bin directory with a regular Console App but I'm not sure how to interpret this. I know it's a System library but I can't use it unless the Nuget is installed, so I don't know if this is a special case. In both scenarios I'm using v6.1.1 of the PowerShell Nuget.

Is this a known bug with Functions v2? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568) that Function can't load runtime assemblies(`[FunctionProject]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\bin\runtimes`) correctly.

The workaround is to move assemblies to output dir `bin` manually. Right click on your function project and `Edit <FunctionProject>.csproj`. Add following items to achieve our goal.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <SDKVersion>6.1.1</SDKVersion>
    <SDKPlatform>win-x86</SDKPlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.directoryservices\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.DirectoryServices.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.management\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.Management.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.management.automation\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Management.Automation.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.management.infrastructure\1.0.0\runtimes\win10-x86\lib\netstandard1.6\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.management\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.utility\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.diagnostics\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.sdk\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.security\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.coreclr.eventing\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.CoreCLR.Eventing.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.consolehost\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.markdownrender\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.MarkdownRender.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.wsman.runtime\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.wsman.management\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.WSMan.Management.dll;
      ">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyRuntimeToBin" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.directoryservices\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.DirectoryServices.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.management\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.Management.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.management.automation\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Management.Automation.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.management.infrastructure\1.0.0\runtimes\win10-x86\lib\netstandard1.6\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.management\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.utility\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.commands.diagnostics\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.sdk\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.security\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.coreclr.eventing\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.CoreCLR.Eventing.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.consolehost\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.powershell.markdownrender\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.MarkdownRender.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.wsman.runtime\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime.dll;
      $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.wsman.management\$(SDKVersion)\runtimes\$(SDKPlatform)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.WSMan.Management.dll;
      " DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
  </Target>
```

Note that `microsoft.management.infrastructure` is set to `win10-x86` on my side(Win10), you may need to change according to your pc platform. Assemblies are x86 as VS uses x86 Function CLi by default, we don't need to worry about it unless we need to work with x64.

Comment: Maybe a bit premature, but now I'm getting a similar error - albeit for a different version of PowerShell (4.0.0.0): "{System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified." This happens when I try to load the MSOnline module so am I assuming correctly there's a PowerShell version mismatch for that module?

Comment: @CoryGehr Sorry it's my omission, try to add `$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.management\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.Management.dll` in two parts.

Comment: At the risk of having an everlasting chain of issues that keep popping up, is there some pattern to how you're including these items? I have another FileNotFound: Could not load file or assembly 'System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Getting to be a bit much - do I need to keep trying and adding these to Copy SourceFiles in my csproj until they stop?

Comment: I added $(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.directoryservices\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.DirectoryServices.dll; and it works now, so thankfully that was the last one. I'm on the right track now I believe - thank you!

Comment: @CoryGehr Glad you overcome it, I agree with you that we may have to fix it according to the error. I notice there're some other assemblies referenced by PSSDK, their runtime assemblies are not moved to `bin` and we don't include them either. So whether we get problem depends on what assemblies our code references internally. This is not an ideal solution at all but we may have to rely on it until the problem is solved by Azure Team.